# Some images can not displayed normally

Tags: java, http, web, proxy

I have wrote a web proxy for HTTP in Java. But when I get a HTML file, only SOME of the images can be displayed normally and the other cannot. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please give a better description of what is happening... What HTTP code its returning? Its even rendering the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the below points are considered.

1. Your **Content Type** is set correctly. Eg. "image/jpeg"
2. The **Character Encoding** is correctly set up while proxying

You might as well try this before writing one for your self unless it is a problem that is specific for you.
https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet